# Light Switch Problem - all Reds and Whites

Tags: lighting, timer, multiway-switch

I have a light switch that I wanted to replace with a timer switch (to control outdoor lights).  When I pulled the old light switch out of the wall, there were 4 wires connected to it:  Two White Wires connected to the two top screws on each side, and 2 red wires connected to the two bottom screws on each side.  What the?  I've never seen a light switch with only red and white wires.  The new timer switch as a black, red, blue and green wire.

(Also, the old switch also did not have a ground wire connected at the bottom of the switch.)

I JUST realized that the outdoor lights have 2 light switches that control them.  (Second question... can I replace one of the switches with a timer switch?)

Help!  (Thanks very much!)

Comment: Nort American wires are not color coded, except for grounds as green/bare, and neutrals as white.  However a hot can be any color except those reserved for ground.

Comment: That super sounds like a 4-way switch.  Are there **three** locations from which this light is controlled?  This is something you will need to know to proceed.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: your description is not completely clear ... `Two White Wires connected to the two top screws on each side` means that there are 4 white wires all together